# Am I using the CSS ID selector appropriately?

Tags: css

I think I may not be understanding "ID's" and Classes in CSS.  In the following example, I am just trying to customize the way the single image is displayed.  I tried to simply just create a custom id for that image, and then in the CSS add the appropriate tags.

The CSS I wrote is not applying to the image.

And on a side note, can I create a custom id in CSS by just doing `<id>` instead of `<p id>`  ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#mypicture {
  outline-color: red; 
  border-radius: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <p id="mypicture"><img src="assets/ben.jpg"></p>
    <h1>Bens's Blog</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Best Poems</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Worst Poems</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, you are using it correctly. If you want the CSS rule to be more specific you can change it to `p#mypicture` In this case you should be applying the CSS to the image itself, not the paragraph tag.

Comment: In your script, you are changing paragraph instead of img (I'm thinking that you want to apply style to immage itself).

Comment: The question does not describe *how* the image rendering should be affected, and the code posted does not include *any* setting that would apply to the `img` element.

Answer (score 3):

You're applying your CSS to the paragraph `<p>` tag. You want this to respect your current DOM:

```
#mypicture img {
  outline-color : red; 
  border-radius : 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better rule set is this:

```
#mypicture > img {
    outline-color: red; 
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

mypicture is a paragraph and you want the styles to be applied to the image within the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the ID directly to the image:

```
<p><img src="assets/ben.jpg" id="mypicture"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `outline-style` is `none`.  So, setting color alone isn't enough to get the outline to appear.  Try setting `outline-style: solid;`.  The will put a square outline around the paragraph.

Since you are also setting `border-radius`, it makes me wonder if your intent is to round the corners on the image.  If so, you should apply the styles to the image instead of the paragraph.  If you want the outline to be rounded as well, use `border` instead of `outline`.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply (on line 13) leave out the paragraph blocks and put the id inside the picture declaration.

```
<img src="assets/ben.jpg" id="mypicture">
```